# swift parse query not returning objects in ascending order

Tags: swift, parse-platform, tableview

My query aims to fetch the objects created by a certain number of users. The following are my codes:

```
var dates = [NSDate]()
var messages = [String]()

        let getUsersQuery = PFQuery(className: "followings")

        getUsersQuery.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)

        getFollowedUsersQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

            if let objects = objects {

                for object in objects {

                    let followedUser = object["followedUser"] as! String

                    let getPostsQuery = PFQuery(className: "posts")

                    getPostsQuery.whereKey("userId", equalTo: followedUser)
                    getPostsQuery.orderByDescending("updatedAt")

                    getPostsQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

                        if let objects = objects {

                            for post in objects {

                                self.dates.append(post.createdAt as NSDate!)
                               self.messages.append(post["message"] as! String)
                        }

                        print(self.dates)

                        self.myTableView.reloadData()
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Here's what come up when I print the dates in the log:

[image]

However, the content in my tableview is not in an ascending order. In fact the post created most recently is at the bottom of the tableview. One thing I noticed is that the posts of a particular user seems to be shown together. So all of one user's post would appear at the top of the tableview no matter another user has created the newest post. Any idea what is going wrong? thanks!

Comment: Look at what your code is doing. Get followed users. For first user. Get posts. Add posts to array. For second user. Get posts. Add posts to array. For third user. etc... Of course it will do what you are saying it is doing. Also, you will be nailing the networking of the device here. You're doing a lot of work on the device that can be pushed off to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a nested query. The array you are trying to get is an of posts. So your query should be on the post table. (Also, your table should be called `post` not `posts`. Table names should always be singular. Each post is called a `post` not a `posts`.

```
let postsQuery = PFQuery(className: "post")
postsQuery.orderByDescending("updatedAt")

let usersQuery = PFQuery(className: "following")
usersQuery.whereKey("follower", equalTo:PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)

// this might need to change depending on what the followed user is called in the `followings` table.
postsQuery.whereKey("userId", matchesKey:"followed", inQuery:usersQuery)

getPostsQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
    if let objects = objects {

    for post in objects {
        self.dates.append(post.createdAt as NSDate!)
        self.messages.append(post["message"] as! String)
    }

    print(self.dates)

    self.myTableView.reloadData()
})
```

Also, you are saving dates and messages in separate arrays. Create a struct or something that has a date and string and have a single array of `Post` objects.